# Perl- Don't allow same line to show twice

Tags: macos, bash, perl

I have a perl script, and I would like prevent input such as

```
Referer: http://www.apple.com/.
Referer: http://www.apple.com/diversity/.
Referer: http://www.apple.com/diversity/.
Referer: http://www.apple.com/diversity/.
Referer: http://www.apple.com/.
Referer: http://www.apple.com/apple-events/september-2015/.
```

from showing the same line twice, with a desired output of

```
Referer: http://www.apple.com/
Referer: http://www.apple.com/diversity/
Referer: http://www.apple.com/
Referer: http://www.apple.com/apple-events/september-2015/
```

Also, how can I get rid of the "." at the end of each line?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about identical non-consecutive lines?

Comment: The line `Referer: http://www.apple.com/` appears twice in your output...I assume you mean you only want to get rid of *consecutive* duplicate lines?

Comment: And how do you feel about sed? (Perl could do it, but that seems like overkill.)

Comment: @Beta What's overkill about `perl -i -ne'next if $_ eq $prev; $prev = $_; s/\.$//; print' /path/to/file` ? ;)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: You mean compared to `sed 's/.$//' filename | uniq`?

Comment: @Beta Ah, but you never said anything about `uniq`. `perl -pe's/.$//' filename | uniq` ;P

Comment: You have a perl script that you want help with ... so show the script. Also, what does this have to do with bash/osx?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Correct, I only want immediately consecutive lines to be removed.

Comment: @Beta Sed is fine, but I don't have a file name, my output is being created live through ettercap being piped through grep to only show 'Referer:'

Comment: No problem, sed can suck on a pipe. (Right now I'm trying to get my uniq-imitating sed command to work, so I can answer @ThisSuitIsBlackNot...)

Answer (score 2):

First ask yourself how would you solve this with pencil and paper, where you are uncovering lines on source page one at a time and then writing them over to another page.  You may have a whiteboard to keep track of things temporarily.

1. Read a line from the source page.
2. If the line hasn't been seen before (ie, it's not written on your whiteboard), write it to your new sheet of paper. (The first line you read will never have been seen before, of course).
3. Save the line you just read by writing it down on a whiteboard.
4. Read the next line from the source page.
5. Look on the whiteboard and see if it's written there.
6. If it is not written on the whiteboard, write it on your destination page.
7. Erase your whiteboard and write the line you just read on it so that you can check again later.
8. Repeat as long as there are lines on the source page remaining to be read.

So here's a Perl implementation of that algorithm. However, the same algorithm could be implemented in many languages.

```
open my $infile, '<', shift or die $!;
my $whiteboard = q{};
while( <$infile> ) {
    print unless $_ eq $whiteboard;
    $whiteboard = $_;
}
```

This could be written as a Perl one-liner like this:

```
perl -ne 'print unless defined $tmp && $tmp eq $_; $tmp = $_;' filename.txt
```

The second part of your question is how to eliminate a trailing dot.  So for the first example, you might do this:

```
open my $infile, '<', shift or die $!;
my $whiteboard = q{};
while( <$infile> ) {
    s/\.$//;
    print unless $_ eq $whiteboard;
    $whiteboard = $_;
}
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
perl -ne 's/\.$//; print unless defined $tmp && $tmp eq $_; $tmp = $_;' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care the order, you can try this:

```
perl -nale 's/\.$//; $h{$_}++; END{foreach(keys %h){print}}' /path/to/file
```

Use `s/\.$//;` to remove `.` at the end of line. And use a hash to remove duplicate lines.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  If the question were "How do I remove duplicates from a file while not caring about order.", it would be great.  But when the question is "How do I prevent contiguous repeats while allowing dis-contiguous  repeats, and at the same time eliminate a dot if it appears at the end of the line?", it's not close.